# PyQt signal between modules

Tags: python, pyqt4

I can not understand one's probably a very simple thing. How from one module (Main.py) make changes (call functions ) in other module (module2.py), which is connected as QDockWidget to MainWindow, and see these changes immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare a signal in the class then connect the signal to a function.

```
class MyClass(QtCore.QObject): # Could be QWidget must be inherited from QObject
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int, int, int) # types to pass values to the method call
    ...


myclass = MyClass()
other = QtGui.QMainWindow()

myclass.mysignal.connect(other.setGeometry)
myclass.mysignal.emit(0, 0, 1, 1)
```

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Comment: @user3471696 Can you mark my answer as correct then?

Comment: Sorry that so late, I didn't know how to do it.